# jquery border color changes onblur function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following problem: I have a form with two text input fields, and I want to change the border color when one of the fields has empty, and get it set back when it has enter anything

```html
<form>
<input class="calc_input" type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" />
<input class="calc_input" type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `onkeyup` event.

```js
document.getElementById('start_date').addEventListener('keyup',function(){
    if (this.value.trim() == ''){ //If value is empty
        this.style.borderColor = 'red';
    }
    else{
        this.style.borderColor = 'black';
    }
});

// Alternate event binding solution
document.getElementById('end_date').onkeyup = function(){
    if (this.value.trim() == ''){ //If value is empty
        this.style.borderColor = 'red';
    }
    else{
        this.style.borderColor = 'black';
    }
}

// jQuery
$('#date').keyup(function(){
    if (this.value.trim() == ''){ //If value is empty
        this.style.borderColor = 'red';
    }
    else{
        this.style.borderColor = 'black';
    }
});

// Drop down list as requested
$('#drop').change(function(){
    if (this.value.trim() == ''){ //If value is empty
        this.style.borderColor = 'red';
    }
    else{
        this.style.borderColor = 'black';
    }
});
```

```css
input[type='text'], select{
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input class="calc_input" type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" />
  <br>
<input class="calc_input" type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" />
  <br>
<input class="calc_input" type="text" name="end_date" id="date" />
  <br>
<select id="drop">
  <option value="">-- Select an item --</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>  
  <option value="2">2</option>  
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: For drop down you are looking for `onchange` event.

Comment: thank you for reply,ha exactly..but here first time you wont select anything and you click submit button..then it will show red color border once you selected any option in that drop-down  it will disappear

Comment: You can bind a function to submit button that checks for every input fields, just like the way to bind a function to a HTML element

Comment: thank you,can you show the way how to do for drop-down

Comment: I added the solution at the bottom of this answer

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#txt').blur(function(){
    $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
  });
});
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66bw5u4h/35/)

Comment: thanks for the answer..but when you enter any data in that text box the red border becomes to none.

Comment: inside the blur function you should check if the field has value.. set color to red only if the value is empty

Comment: You can set for that also by using focus() event

Answer (score 0):

Reformat your html code as follows and write click event for form submit button:

```
<form class="inputForm">
    <input class="calc_input" type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" />
    <input class="calc_input" type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" />
    <input class="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".btnSubmit").click(function () {
                $(".inputForm input[type='text']").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == "")
                        $(this).css('border-color', 'red')
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

or you want on textbox change event then replace javascript code with this 


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".inputForm input[type='text']").on("blur", function () {
            if ($(this).val() != "")
                $(this).css('border-color', 'initial');
            else
                $(this).css('border-color', 'red')
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go about like this:

```
$("input").change(function () {
        var value = (this.value);
        // If the text box is empty, add a red border
        if (value =="") {
            $(this).css("border", "2px solid red");
        }
        // Else if the value is not empty, add a black border
        else {
            $(this).css("border", "2px solid lightgreen");
        }
    }).trigger("change");
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/LsjzeyL9/1/